# Start noip application before login

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup

How to start noip2 automatically before login?
I tried with this for 3 hours, editing /etc/rc.local, /etc/init.d/rc.local, running script /etc/init.d with update-rclocal, nothing seem to work, even reinstalled Ubuntu. Any Hint? :{

(13.04)

Comment: How do you start `noip2` after login?

Comment: after "make install" its just writing noip2, the file is located in /usr/local/bin/noip2

Comment: The noip2 package includes a boot script. If you used that instead the binary it would have worked without problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file (using sudo -i gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` command) and append the line:

```
session-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/noip2
```

Comment: It works, yay:P